# Where is the information about database firewall rules stored in Azure?

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

Where is the information about database firewall rules stored in Azure?

I executed below line on Azure SQL Database
EXECUTE sp_set_database_firewall_rule N'database firewall','x.x.x.x','x.x.x.x';

I worked and I got information that one row was affected. Where is this row?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SELECT * FROM sys.firewall_rules` shows the firewall settings at the server level. Fortunetaly I found what i wanted executing:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.database_firewall_rules
```

I did not have to switch context to the master database.

Answer (score 0):

Change your context to the master database and execute the following:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.firewall_rules
```